# Problem with parsing XML with multiple namespace into SQL

Tags: sql, xml, openxml

I've got problem with parsing informations from XML into SQL with double namespace.
Have a look at this code:

```
DECLARE @Handle AS INT; -- The handle of the XML data, passed to sp_xml_preparedocument
DECLARE @Xml AS NVARCHAR(1000); -- The XML document for this example


SET @Xml = N'
<SiBikNet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types">
 <BIK_REQUEST>
    <siBikNetResponse>
        <consentDate>2018-07-29</consentDate>
        <citizenshipStatus>citizen</citizenshipStatus>
        <nationality>PL</nationality>
        <pesel>123</pesel>
    </siBikNetResponse>
 </BIK_REQUEST>
</SiBikNet>';


EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @Handle OUTPUT , @Xml, N'<SiBikNet xmlns:t="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types"/>'; --Prepare a parsed document 

SELECT *
FROM
       OPENXML(@Handle,'/t:SiBikNet/t:BIK_REQUEST/t:siBikNetResponse', 2)
           WITH (   nationality NVARCHAR(10) 't:nationality',
                    pesel  NVARCHAR(10)      't:pesel '
                );

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @Handle;
```

Which gives me proper output in forms of table with 2 columns.
But when I will add one row with double namespace:  then I cannot parse this informations :

```
DECLARE @Handle AS INT; -- The handle of the XML data, passed to sp_xml_preparedocument
DECLARE @Xml AS NVARCHAR(1000); -- The XML document for this example


SET @Xml = N'
<SiBikNet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types">
 <BIK_REQUEST xmlns="">
    <siBikNetResponse>
        <consentDate>2018-07-29</consentDate>
        <citizenshipStatus>citizen</citizenshipStatus>
        <nationality>PL</nationality>
        <pesel>123</pesel>
    </siBikNetResponse>
 </BIK_REQUEST>
</SiBikNet>';


EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @Handle OUTPUT , @Xml, N'<SiBikNet xmlns:t="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types"/>'; --Prepare a parsed document 

SELECT *
FROM
       OPENXML(@Handle,'/t:SiBikNet/t:BIK_REQUEST/t:siBikNetResponse', 2)
           WITH (   nationality NVARCHAR(10) 't:nationality',
                    pesel  NVARCHAR(10)      't:pesel '
                );

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @Handle;
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I get stuck with anonymous namespaces or oddball namespace combinations, the simplest way is to just use the XPath function `local-name()`.  Like this:

```
DECLARE @Handle AS INT; -- The handle of the XML data, passed to sp_xml_preparedocument
DECLARE @Xml AS NVARCHAR(1000); -- The XML document for this example


SET @Xml = N'
<SiBikNet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types">
 <BIK_REQUEST xmlns="">
    <siBikNetResponse>
        <consentDate>2018-07-29</consentDate>
        <citizenshipStatus>citizen</citizenshipStatus>
        <nationality>PL</nationality>
        <pesel>98070902702</pesel>
    </siBikNetResponse>
 </BIK_REQUEST>
</SiBikNet>';


EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @Handle OUTPUT , @Xml, N'<SiBikNet xmlns:t="https://www.ws.bik.pl/ws/ki/2v2/types"/>'; --Prepare a parsed document 

SELECT *
FROM
       OPENXML(@Handle,'/*[local-name()="SiBikNet"]/*[local-name()="BIK_REQUEST"]/*[local-name()="siBikNetResponse"]', 2)
           WITH (   nationality NVARCHAR(10) ,--'t:nationality',
                    pesel  NVARCHAR(10)      --'t:pesel '
                );

EXEC sys.sp_xml_removedocument @Handle;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. That works well. But I got another question connected with it in separate thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831030/problem-with-parsing-xml-with-multiple-nodes-into-sql